# SCSS multiple properties in mixin

Tags: css, sass

Take a look at the following example:

```
@mixin placeholder ($color) {
  &.-moz-placeholder {
    color: $color;
  }

  &:-ms-placeholder {
    color: $color;
  }
}

@include placeholder(#999);
```

But instead I want to insert multiple properties not just the color in the placeholder style. Like this:

```
@mixin placeholder ($properties) {
  &.-moz-placeholder {
    $properties;
  }

  &:-ms-placeholder {
    $properties;
  }
}

@include placeholder(color: #999, text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #000);
```

Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @dave suggests, you can accomplish this using Sass's `@content` directive. Here's what your example would look like using that syntax:

```
@mixin placeholder {
  &.-moz-placeholder {
    @content;
  }

  &:-ms-placeholder {
    @content;
  }
}

@include placeholder {
  color: #999;
  text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #000;
};
```

Note that to pass a content block, you use curly braces rather than parentheses. You can read more in the [SASS documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-content).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for "Passing Content Blocks to a Mixin"?

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-content